# Internet Explorer caching issue

Tags: php, mysql, internet-explorer, caching

I have a website that offers a service to subscribed members. It has been reported to me that one of the pages that has a form used to submit data to a mysql database has not been displaying saved changes.

The form should display back data that has been stored in the database. (After the page has been submitted)

I thought this was odd, as I was under the impression that php pages could not be cached.

I have tried using:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Expires: -1");
```

and private mode in IE8 but this made no difference.

This problem does not occur when using any other browser other than Internet explorer 6/7/8

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hold Ctrl and press F5 to bypass the browser cache on reloads. For everything else, post some code for us to see.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you append a garbage variable to the end of the  URL string? Does it still cache it?

```
http://site.com/path/page?random=JH4kdhkj3
```

It not the best because you clutter up the URL, but I'm curious what happens.

Answer (score 1):

You should trace your traffic with a HTTP Debugger like Fiddler, and read http://www.enhanceie.com/redir/?id=httpperf to understand how HTTP caching works.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem with one of our clients. IE cache settings were set to "`Never check for new version`". The issue was fixed after setting it to "`Automatic`". I know this question is 4 years old but I hope my answer can still help others who are struggling with IE.

Answer (score 0):

What about adding the following in the :

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses guys.

After looking into the matter further, the problem seems to be with session_start(), if I remove this from the page the data entry and display works as intended.

I'm not sure what the exact problem is with sessions in IE, but I'm going to install fiddler and see if I can find out whats going on.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to post back to the page where the changes are expected to be found with a nonsensical query string to force browser to get the new page.. Just a thought.